# PHP + IIS7 + X64 OS (Windows 7 or Server 2008)

Tags: windows-server-2008, php, iis-7, 64-bit, windows-7

I'm going to answer my own question here, but I thought this might be important enough to post so that it would be indexed for the next person who runs into my situation.

**Problem**: I can not seem to get PHP code to execute on a x64 bit version ofIIS7, whether it be in my desktop, Windows 7, or the application's final destination on Windows Server 2008.  Every time I try and look at a test php document to confirm installation, I only see the source code.

I've followed the documentation from PHP, from iis.net, blogs, howtos, just about anywhere I can find that Google would send me.  I tried the web installer, tried manual installations instead of the MSI, tried version 5.3.5, tried version 5.2.17, but no matter what, the code would never execute.  I even tried registering .eric files with PHP FastCGI Module, but same result, php source code only.

Answer (score 0):

After about an hour or two a day for 5 days trying to figure this out, I started walking through the php.ini file.

Being a usual LAMP user, I always coded `<? // phpcode // ?>` .   Always worked after a fresh install on LAMP.

With IIS/Windows installer of PHP, `<? (short tags)` is turned off to avoid conflicts with ASP.

Once I added `<?php  //phpcode ?>`, everything worked!

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer.  

Being try to find a solution for a good few hours.

All works now!